# Tuple Indexout of range error in Python

Tags: python

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import math
import sys
from decimal import Decimal

conn=mdb.connect('localhost','root','','testdb')
c=conn.cursor()

user_id=str(sys.argv[1])
lati=str(sys.argv[2])
longi=str(sys.argv[3])
radius=int(str(sys.argv[4]))



c.execute("Select user_id from users")
userids=c.fetchall()

c.execute("Select lati, longi from userloc")
locations=c.fetchall()

c.execute("Select i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 from userint")
interests=c.fetchall()

c.execute("Select organization,job_profile from userprof")
profiles=c.fetchall()

c.execute("Select i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 from userint where user_id=%s"%user_id)
recc_user_int=c.fetchall()

c.execute("Select organization,job_profile from userprof where             user_id=%s"%user_id)
recc_user_prof=c.fetchall()

temp=""

affinity_score=0.0
alpha=0.0
beta=0.0
gamma=0.0

size=len(locations)

outp=""
j=0
while j<size:
userb=int(userids[j][0])
if(user_id != userb):
    #print(j)
    lat1=float(locations[j][0])
    long1=float(locations[j][1])
    if(float(lati)>lat1):
        dlat = float(float(lati) - lat1)
    else:
        dlat = float(lat1 - float(lati))
    if(float(longi)>long1):
        dlon = float(float(longi) - long1)
```

Getting the following error :
File "C:\Python27\recommend.py", line 50, in 
userb=int(userids[j][0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Please help. It was working propery and suddenly the error comes this morning and the script is not working

Comment: What is `userids` here? You are getting this error because you are trying to access an item which isn't available.

Comment: @AKS I have made no changes and it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: well, we would love to go to yesterday and see this working, if some of us have a time machine. Unfortunately, you have to debug. `tuple index out of range` simply means, nothing available at given index, this is the code probably `long1=float(locations[j][1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
userb=int(userids[j][0])
```

causes the problem.

And to solve the problem ..... have a look on what error says.
"Index out of range" means that u are trying to access the element( of the tuple) that does not exist, like
You want to access the third element but the tuple has only two elements

So the error is somewhere above in your code when u work with that "userids" tuple

If the tuple can be diffferent at time like one day it is empty second day not ( for examplewhen you get the info from server or something like that) u should take care of it with "try except" blocks or before working with the tuple recognize its size

**Edit:** 
And it gave you the error bbecause there were not any userids in the db but after they are added it works fine.